# GoogleSheet: if condition, set cell value, else allow user input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a google sheet where checkboxes control if a column must be included or not.
Each column represents one person, the checkbox on top of the column determines if the person must be taken into account into the computation.

The calculation consists in determining how much each person must pay (`Monthly installments`), according to:

- a starting contribution (`Input`)
- a percentage of the remaining amount to be repaid (`Proportion` of `300 000,00€-110 000,00€`)

My data is structured like this:

[image: My spreadsheet]

My problem is that, when I uncheck one of the columns, the percentage associated with the person stays the same and this introduces an error in the calculation: the sum of the `Input` and the `Monthly installments` is no longer equal to the total sum `300 000,00€`.

[image: Problem when unchecking a column]

What I'd like to achieve is:

- when unchecked, to automatically set to 0% the value of the `Proportion` cell
- when checked, to allow user to enter any percentage in the `Proportion` cell

[image: What I'd like to achieve]

Do you have any idea on how to allow simultaneously **user input** and **value based on a condition**?

Thanks a lot!

---

### EDIT

You can find [here a working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1so3_tiUSVnWV4ilDF3lb-q2iE_QjrBtpQ1FNsUQWJgo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you using any Sheets formulae for this? If so, would you mind posting those here as well?

Comment: Indeed there is a few, I've just posted a google sheet example directly

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to have both formula and manual input in one cell. Once you write something, you erase the formula. If you want to let manual input and have formula too, you should make extra space for this. You can also use conditional formatting to mark cells that are without formula. Then you can quickly see what is not calculated anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this script to your Sheets can solve your task

```
function onEdit(e) {

  let row = e.range.getRow(),
      col = e.range.getColumn(),
      firstCol = 2,
      lastCol  = 6;
  
  if (sheet.getName() == 'MONEY' && col>=firstCol && col<=lastCol){
    switch (row){
      case 1: 
        if (!e.range.getValue()) e.range.offset(3,0).clearContent();
      break;
      case 4:
        if (!e.range.offset(-3,0).getValue()) e.range.clearContent();
      break;
    }
  }  
}
```